# Android AdMob SDK with multiple ads on the same screen

Tags: java, android, admob

Can you have more than one ad on the same screen in android using AdMob SDK?

Comment: if You add more than one Your App will be removed from playstore

Comment: Can we able to display multiple ads using admob in same screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be possible but its not allowed: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en

**EDIT:**
It's not explicitly disallowed anymore. Please review these policies for correct ad placement: [AdMob & AdSense policies](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128543?hl=en)

Comment: This is typical example, where link is not enough and citation is (was) needed.

Comment: @Velda you're right cause google change it's policies this answer isn't correct anymore. Placing two Banners on the same page isn't explicitly disallowed anymore.